# How do I go about creating cloth with the right amount of rigidity to hold itself up?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I've started learning blender on my own in maybe the last 2 months, so as a challenge I've tried to recreate the [English coronation crown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig5jm.jpg), but I've had a really hard time figuring out how to do the purple cloth part in the middle.
Essentially it looks like its the cloth itself that is holding it up through its rigidity while still being a little slumped in. I've tried finding video guides online but I can't seem to find one that deals with my specific issue. So what do you think would be the easiest way to go about it? My guess would be that figuring out some sort of simulation would be the most realistic but I've got no idea how to mess around with the physics of the fabric to make it look close to the picture. So I ask you, what is your suggestion? And please remember that I'm pretty new to blender so please keep the language simplistic as I'm not really up to speed with the more advanced terms. Thank you very much in advance :)

[image: English coronation crown]

Comment: Have you considered using the cloth grab brush in sculpt mode? With that you can just pull things around in a clothy kind of way.

Comment: I could certainly try, although I'm not very confident in sculpt mode.

Comment: I don't think it would be that difficult.  You won't need to sculpt the folds so much.  Just push things down, pull things around a bit and maybe inflate things.  Just a thought at least.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that :)

Comment: @MarkGrant thanks for the post. Answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)